# How do I determine the map type (e.g. normal, satellite) in HERE?

Tags: javascript, here-api

I am need to determine the current map type (normal, satellite).  In Bing, this was as simple as map.getMapTypeId().

Answer (score 0):

To get map type we can use `getBaseLayer` method which should return object with `type_name` property like this:

```
map.getBaseLayer().type_name; // normal, satellite
```

Docs can be found here https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.22.1/api_reference/H.Map.html#getBaseLayer.